# Pasar datos de una vista a layout - plantilla laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto en laravel5.6, soy muy nuevo haciéndolo, tengo ya la ruta y el controlador funcionando en una vista:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content') 
 @foreach($grupos as $grupo)
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
  <h3 class="namePost"><strong><a href="#">{{ $grupo-> name }}</a></strong></h3>
 </div>
 @endforeach
@endsection
```

el controlador es:

```html
Public function grupos(){
     $grupos = Grupo::orderBy('id','DESC')->where('status','PUBLISHED')->paginate();
        return view('grupo.inicio', compact('grupos'));
    }
```

el modelo App\Grupo es el siguiente:

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grupo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
  'user_id','name','slug','address','body','file','claveMapaGoogle','status'
 ];

 public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }
}
```

quiero hacer que {{ $grupo-> name }} funcione en una de mis plantillas que se llama 'layouts.base'

buscando información  me sugirieron lo siguiente:

en AppServiceProvider:

```html
   <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Grupo;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(['layouts.base'], function ($view) {
        $view->with('grupos', Grupo::count());
    });
}  

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```

pero me sale el siguiente error:

> **Class 'App\Providers\Grupo' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-radio\resources\views\web\inicio.blade.php)**

Gracias de antemano. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El modelo `Grupo` existe dentro del namespace de `App`, por lo tanto debes invocarlo a través de su namespace para que funcione:

Agrégalo justo después de la llamada a la clase `ServiceProvider`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Grupo;
```

Comment: hola muchas gracias por responder: hice lo que me indicaste me da el siguiente error: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: grupo (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-radio\resources\views\layouts\base.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-radio\resources\views\layouts\base.blade.php)
Previous exceptions